# Javascript foreach question: how to pick out the number element to form new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I have some tasks to handle in my daily jobs, so I need to do it in a automatic way. My task is:

1. there will be some messages sent to my IM, and I need to append the first, second & third number to each links with a "|".
2. if there only 2 numbers in the number line, a 0 is needed in the first place.

For example, in the cleanResult example, I need it to be done like:

```
finalResult = ["https://www.example.com/firstlink|500",
"https://www.example.com/firstlink|150",
"https://www.example.com/firstlink|30",
"https://www.exmaple.com/secondlink|600",
"https://www.exmaple.com/secondlink|150",
"https://www.exmaple.com/secondlink|30",
"https://www.example.com/thirdlink|500",
"https://www.example.com/thirdlink|150",
"https://www.example.com/thirdlink|30",
"https://www.example.com/forthlink|600",
"https://www.example.com/forthlink|100",
"https://www.example.com/forthlink|20",
"https://www.example.com/fithlink|0",
"https://www.example.com/fithlink|200",
"https://www.example.com/fithlink|50"
]
```

Here's the codes I had done so far:

```
const urlRegex = /(https?\:\/\/)?([^\.\s]+)?[^\.\s]+\.[^\s]+/gi;
const digitRegex = /^(?=.*\d)[\d ]+$/;

cleanResult = ["https://www.example.com/firstlink",
"https://www.exmaple.com/secondlink",
"https://www.example.com/thirdlink",
"500    150    30",
"https://www.example.com/forthlink",
"600    100     20",
"https://www.example.com/fithlink",
"200   50"
]

cleanResult.forEach((item, index) => {
       if (item.match(digitRegex)) {
              //codes I don't know how to do...
      }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are elements in `cleanResult` always either a URL or a number? In that case, you could just check the first character of the string to see if it's a number (basically a non-url). If it's not a URL, then we know it's numbers, and we can do something with the URL, which should the the previous element:

```
// If it's a URL, we will store it here for future use
let currentURL = ''

cleanResult.forEach((item, index) => {
  // Get the first character of this string
  const first = item[0]

  if (!Number.isInteger(first)) {
    // This is NOT a number, so must be a URL, 
    // let's store it in our variable to use in the next loop
    currentURL = item

  } else {
    // This IS a number, which means we need to do a few things:
    // 1. Split into separate numbers
    // 2. Create a new URL pattern from each number
    // 3. Push to finalResult

    // 1. Split by tab delimiter (?)

    // splits by tab, and returns an array
    const numbers = item.split('\t')

    // 2. Create a new URL pattern from each number
    numbers.forEach((n) {
      // This should now give you the URL + | + the number:
      // ex: https://example.com/firstlink|500
      const newURL = currentURL + '|' + n

      // 3. push to the finalResult array
      finalResult.push(newURL)
    })
  }
})
```

I haven't tested it, but this is the process that I generally use: break it into smaller tasks and take it one step at a time. I also didn't use regex, just to make it easier. We're assuming that you will receive either a URL or a list of numbers separated by a tab. This means you can afford to keep it a bit simple.

I'm sure there are way more efficient ways to do it and in a lot fewer lines, but if you're just learning JS or programming, there is nothing wrong with being extra verbose so that you can understand early concepts.

Comment: thank you very much for your inspiration. I learned a lot from your codes.  The only problem you seemed to miss is that the link (or links) only uses that following number line.  In my example, the first 3 links use the number in line #4, and forth link uses the following link. It seems that your codes do not address this problem.